# What is a good project to learn Windows Forms programming in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to learn c# so I can do some desktop developing. I've developed command-line C# applications and wanted to expand to Desktop applications.

I was thinking of create a screenshot tool like Jing or maybe a plugin for outlook to sync contact information with a service like Google.

What are your thoughts? My past experience is with web applications built in PHP.

Answer (score 9):

I would try to start with something fairly contained, which only touched a few new technologies. For instance, if you want to learn Windows Forms, write something which uses that but *doesn't* need to talk to Outlook, Google, or the Win32 API. Once you've got the hang of Windows Forms, try *one* extra technology - try displaying your Google Contacts and do offline editing, for example. Then add another technology... etc.

In my experience it's hard enough to learn one new technology at a time - but that's far quicker than trying to learn two or more in one go. You inevitably get to the stage where you don't know where the problems are, and you have no confidence in any of your code because it's *all* new. This is particularly important if you're still fairly new to the *language* as well - although I'm glad to hear you started with some console apps :)

Sorry if that sounds like I'm being a wet blanket, and I realise it sounds like you'll take far longer to get to something useful that way, but I think you're more likely to be successful in the long run.

Answer (score 6):

Find something that most importantly interests and excites you. If you pick something too boring that you don't care about you'll only give up before you get anywhere, and won't benefit at all. Don't do a rubbish project for the sake of learning a language. Do a good project, and do it in a new language as a side effect.

Answer (score 3):

Make a notepad clone. While being fairly simple it will give you a primer in some basic Windows Forms mechanisms such as using menus and reacting on their events, getting input from controls for storage on disk, reading from disk and updating controls, using Docking and Anchoring and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter clients are the new `hello world`.

I read that somewhere the other day. I can't personally comment on its fitness for your goal.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the possessive its... are we running short on availability of other characters though or did you just not like my casual tone?

Comment: He made you sound smarter. Be grateful.

Comment: Haha... that's true and I can use all the help I can get :-)

Comment: You're under 140 now, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do something that you did before, but in another language. Then you won't have to think about most of the architecture of the particular task again, but you'll be able to compare the languages, the frameworks and their approaches.

*I bet you'll learn a lot about your previous language as well doing this excercise.*

Answer (score 1):

A good project would be a simple windows form. You simply have a chance to put everything together. Or at least see a bigger picture.
You can make it as complicated as you want, without sticking to one area.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a specific project is pointless. Think of something that interests you, or an application you want/need, then start making it - searching Stackoverflow/Google/MSDN/etc whenever you can't guess how to do a specific task.

For example, I had to make kiosk application that allowed customers to signup to a companies mailing-list. I tried using the Ruby framework Shoes, but it didn't work correctly on the laptop the application was to run on. Visual C# seemed like a better fit, and would almost certainly run correctly..

So I installed Visual C# Express, added a few labels and a button. I double clicked the button, and realised I didn't know the code to create a new WinForm window.. So I searched Google for "visual C# open new dialogue" or something, and I found out I had to add a new form, then call `NewForm newwindow = new NewForm(); newwindow.show();` or similar.

Then, I added the username/email fields, then searched for "how to display an alert box" and checked I could display the form values.

That all worked, so now I had to decide how to store the emails. I had heard good things about LINQ to SQL, so looked into that, decided I wanted to use SQL Server CE (so I didn't have to install/run SQL Server on the laptop). That resulted in more searching around for how to make LINQ to SQL work with SQL Server CE..

Finally, I wanted to have a configuration panel to change the title/button strings etc (accessible via a certain keyboard shortcut).. A Google search revealed how to catch keystrokes, and I asked a Stackoverflow question about representing the settings (using a PanelView or something)

..anyway, the point of that slightly long, rambling and not terribly interesting story is.. You can learn many new technologies at once, as long as you have a specific application in mind (and you're determined to finish it!)

I learned C#, WinForms, SQL Server CE, LINQ to SQL, and simple application publishing stuff in a day - creating a functioning, useful application in the process - simply with a combination of prodding around, Google searches and Stackoverflow..